# How do you duplicate an IntelliJ Android project?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have an existing project in IntelliJ 14 for Android, and I am trying to duplicate the project. I'm not using VCS because these projects are small and more experimental than anything.

The problem I am having is that if I just simply copy the project folder, rename it, and begin making changes, every time I add an activity IntelliJ adds it to the original project, not the currently opened one, and I get warnings about files not being part of the project.

If I rename the original project folder to something else then open the copy, I get "Cannot resolve symbol" with all the resources.

I'm confused as to why something as simple as renaming a project folder breaks a bunch of links within that project.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate a project:

- Copy the folder
- Rename it
- Rename the `iml` file into the project folder with the same name as the folder

If you want to duplicate a module:

- Copy the folder
- Rename it
- Rename the `iml` file into the modle folder with the same name as the folder
- Edit `settings.gradle` file in your project folder and replace old occurences of the old module name with the new one.

Comment: @AppCrafter, if you my answer helped you, may I ask you accept it as the correct one :)

Comment: this didn't work for me there are a bunch of references throughout the module that have to be renamed such as the xml files in the .idea and probably in many other places.  I miss the simple eclipse way: copy project and paste, how simple is that?

Answer (score 1):

I can think about different reasons for project duplication.
Asuming that the build tool is Gradle. If you want to make variants of a project, with not so many differences, and want to keep the majority of the components in common, the solutions is the mechanism of `Build Variants` and `Flavours`.
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

When a build variant becomes so different from original that it's no longer useful to keep them together, the you can get the code and put it in a different android project, and move it to another repository if required.